# Example of a homeomorphism with certain conditions

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

> **Question:** Give an example of sets $X,Y \subset \mathbb R^n$ and points $a \in X$, $ \in Y$ such that $X - \{a\}$ and $Y - \{b\}$ are homeomorphic, albeit $X$ and $Y$ are **not** homeomorphic.

**Attempt:** Take $X = S[\hat{x} ; r] \cup S[\hat{y} ; s] $ and $a \in X$ such that $\{a\} = S[\hat{x} ; r]  \cap S[\hat{y} ; s] $. Take $Y = (x,y)$ and $b \in Y$ such that $b = \frac{x + y}{2}$. Then we have that

$$X-\{a\} = S[\hat{x} ; r] - \{a\} \cup S[\hat{y} ; s] - \{a\} \ \ \text{and} \ \ Y -\{b\} = (x,b) \cup (b,y) $$

Consider the follwing functions:

$$\begin{align}\psi_1 : S[\hat{x} ; r]- \{a\} &\to S^1-\{p\}\\x &\mapsto \frac{1}{r}(x - \hat{x})\end{align} \tag{1}$$

$$\begin{align}\psi_2 : S^1- \{p\} &\to \mathbb R\\(x,y) &\mapsto \frac{x}{1 - y}\end{align} \tag{2}$$

$$\begin{align}\psi_3 : \mathbb R &\to (0,1)\\x &\mapsto \frac{x}{1 + |x|}\end{align} \tag{3}$$

$$\begin{align}\psi_4 : (0,1) &\to (x,b)\\t &\mapsto(1-t)b + tx\end{align} \tag{4}$$

where $p$ is the north pole of $S^1$.

Then $\xi_1  = \psi_4 \circ \psi_3 \circ \psi_2 \circ \psi_1$ is a homeomorphism between $S[\hat{x} ; r]- \{a\}$ and $(x,b)$. Analogously we may find a $\xi_2$ a homeomorphism between $S[\hat{y} ; s] - \{a\}$ and $(b,y)$.

Now as $$S[\hat{x} ; r] - \{a\} \cap S[\hat{y} ; s] - \{a\} = \emptyset$$ we define the  function $\xi: S[\hat{x} ; r] - \{a\}  \cup S[\hat{y} ; s] - \{a\} \to (x,b) \cup (b,y)$ by

$$\xi(t) = \begin{cases}\xi_1 (t)\,\, ,\,\,  t \in S[\hat{x} ; r] - \{a\}\\\xi_2(t) \,\, , \,\, t \in S[\hat{y} ; s] - \{a\}\end{cases}$$

Therefore we have that $\xi$ is in fact a homeomorphism between $X-\{a\}$ and $Y- \{b\}$.

1) Is anything wrong so far?

2) I still need to show that there is no homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ and I was thinking of maybe working on $f^{-1}(b)$ but I couldn't reach anywhere so far. Any hints?

Comment: What is $S[\hat x, r]$?

Comment: The sphere $S[\hat{x} ; r] = \{x \in \mathbb R^2 ; \|x - \hat{x}\| = r\}$.

Comment: So your solution is only for $n=2$?

Comment: At first, yes. The question here asks for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic, notice that every point of $Y$ is a cut point, but $X$ has only one cut point.

Comment: I didn't know what a cut point was. I guess function number (1) is wrong. What do you think?

Comment: At north pole? I was thinking it's definitely not $a$ in $S^1 - \{a\}$.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really make sense to say $S[\hat x, r] - \{a\} \to S^1 - \{a\}$, because $S^1$ doesn't necessarily contain $a$. To make your computations easier, you could specify exactly $X = S[(-1,0),1] \cup S[(1,0),1]$.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that. But as it is, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me! I guess the moral of this is to show why topologists prove things by drawing pictures :P

Comment: Cool, I'm only checking the definition of cut point here.

Comment: I should also show that cut points are preserved under homeomorphism, huh?

Comment: Yeah, $x\in X$ is a cut point (for connected $X$) if $X - \{x\}$ is disconnected. It's not too hard to show that a homeomorphism must send cut points to cut points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22563/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-william-stagner).

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb {R},$ let $X=[-1,1], a = 0, Y = [0,1)\cup [2,3], b = 3.$ These sets can also be seen as lying in any $\mathbb {R}^n.$

Comment: That works as well, it's just that I was thinking of that example first and I was trying to make sense of it.